# Htaccess rewrite rule not working on htaccess magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I added this code to my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^furniture/([0-9]+)/?$ furniture.php?color=$1 [NC,L]
```

Suppose i have a link like **http://domain.com/furniture.php?color=26** on my site that filters my product according to the color and when I enter/type to my address bar like **http://domain.com/furniture/26** it should list all products with that color id(color=26), but my page redirects me to 404 NOT Found! This is my [reference link](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)!, Im using Magento. I dont know where/what do I missed on my code. Hope someone could have me an explanation why is it not working and lend me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you implement this